# how to read content of a file in a environment variable in windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

is there an equivalent in Windows Command to the following command in bash :

```
variable='cat mytextfile'
```

I found answers on the net, but they use loop or complicated ways... they're is probably a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following command, which works for me

```
set /p myVar=<myFile.txt
```